# Laurent Series of $f(z)=(z+1)\sin\frac{z^{2}+2z+5}{(z+1)^{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

We are asked to find the Laurent series for the following function.

$$f(z)=(z+1)\sin\frac{z^{2}+2z+5}{(z+1)^{2}}$$

Around the point $$z_{0}=-1$$

I have tried to factor the inside of sine, to no avail.

I know that $\sin(z)$ at $z=0$ is a simple pole, even if the inside is a square like $(z+1)^2$.

Furthermore, I think term $(z+1)$ multiplied by sine, might be suggestive of a derivative of some sort.

Other than that, I am lost as far as what to do with the inside of sine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. $z^2+2z+5 = (z+1)^2+4$
2. Use a Taylor series of sine, but not the usual *one.*

I think this should be enough to get you started. If you have no idea how to use these hints, I can give you more hints.

---

Edit #1.

I thought making "one" italics would be a good hint...

Basically, I was suggesting that you use the Taylor series of sin centered at 1.

But @Santosh Linkha's comment might work better, since you'll be able to use the Maclaurin series of sin and cos.

In either case, you'll have $\sin(1)$ and $\cos(1)$ appear as coefficients of your series.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more hint on the second one? Thanks.

Comment: @user101998 how about using formula $\sin(a+b)$ ??

Comment: Using the sin sum formula will allow the @user101998 to use the Maclaurin series of sin and cos, so that might be easier.

Comment: @user101998: I actually recommend Braindead's approach. The point is that if you want to identify the behaviour around a point, you always perform asymptotic expansions around that point and not somewhere else. In special cases there may be other methods, but it would be ad-hoc and not generalizable.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: @JohnLennon Yup. Or were you asking the OP?

Comment: Still trying....

Comment: @user101998 What is the Taylor series of $\sin$ centered at 1?

Comment: I got it. Thanks!